# In an iOS View, how can I display a list or table of an object's variable values, hiding rows where the variable's value is nil?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and iOS, coming from Android. I have a problem that seems as though it can be solved in many ways, though **none of them feel like the right way.**

I am using Swift 4 and Xcode 9.2.

**The problem:** I have objects which are just instances of a single data class. An object has around 40 variables all of which are strings, integers, or Boolean values. I am passing one of these objects from View A to View B through a Segue. In View B, I want to display a row for each variable. Each row will contain two labels, one that describes the variable, and one that displays the variable's value. For example, if I have `myObject.foo` which is equal to `10`, the row will display "Foo: 10". **However,** if the value is of `foo` is `nil`, I don't want to display anything (not "Foo:" or "nil").

Effectively, **I want to be able to programmatically inflate a number of subviews that each contain a pair of labels, then individually set the labels' text or hide/remove the subview entirely.**

**So far, I have tried** a number of methods, but none of them seemed very elegant:

- First, I tried a table with dynamic cells. I set up a View Controller that had a Table View Controller embedded within it. But it didn't seem like there was a clear way to give the table my object and have it only generate a row for each non-nil variable. In Android, I could just make a layout file that depicted a row, inflate one of those layouts into a parent layout as many times as I needed, and target the text fields they contained directly from the code.
- Second, I used the same setup as above, but with static cells. I manually made a cell for each variable my object had, thinking I could just target each label and set its text to the value of the variable. This felt weird, because I had to make about 40 cells in the storyboard editor manually, one for each variable my object has. **This worked, but then came the problem of hiding cells.** From what I gathered, you can't just completely hide a cell in a table like you could in Android. This stunned me. The best I could do was make the cell invisible with `.isHidden`, which would leave a blank white space it its place. I also tried to set cell heights to `0`, but I was surprised to find that I couldn't set the height property of a cell through its outlet.
- Third, I scrapped the whole thing and made a vertical stack view. I started adding subviews, but as I said, I'd need around 40 of them, and it just felt *insane* to make each of those manually in the storyboard editor, with all of the constraints and everything. I didn't feel like this was the "right way," either.

Like I said, I am coming from Android and I feel as though I am going about this all wrong. Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this in iOS?

Comment: Please let me know why this question received a downvote so that I can reword it to be more helpful and ask better questions in the future. I understand that it was a bit wordy, but I wanted to clearly express what I tried and why I was uncertain. I hope the answer and my comment on the answer can help other people in the future who are coming from other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right the first time: use a UITableView. The UITableViewDataSource methods supply the data in real time.

- To remove a cell, remove that datum from the source and call `reloadData` (or a similar reload method). Note that you can maintain a master list of all the data elsewhere; the data are removed only from the version of the list that acts as data source to the table. This is called *filtering* the table.
- Another common option is to use the UITableViewDelegate methods to configure the heights of the cells so that some cells (the ones you want to hide) have zero height.

Comment: Thank you, the way you worded this clarified a lot for me. For my case, I decided to go down the path of the second option. I used static cells and hid them as needed using the `heightForRowAt indexPath` method. Specifically, I set up a `switch` on `indexPath.row`, having a case for each row position (0, 1, 2, 3...). In each case, I checked if the variable that would be displayed in the row is `nil`. If it is `nil`, I set the height of that row to zero by using `return 0;`. As a switch `default`, I return a default row height (I chose `60.0`).